# How to formulate COUPNCD

Tags: excel

I am looking for the algorithm of COUPNCD or a formula that gives the equivalent of COUPNCD. This formula gives next coupon date given settlement date, maturity date and the coupon frequency.

Comment: Do you the equivalent in Java or c++ ?

Comment: [Excel Financial Functions in F#](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Excel-Financial-functions-6afc7d42/sourcecode?fileId=24126&pathId=36733381)